# Using REGEX in Visualforce

Tags: apex

I want to be able to render an element if my custom field matches a certain pattern.

Custom Field Name: Code__c
Pattern: (any character)19-10-11-12(any character)

How can this be achieved in Visualforce?

The rendered condition in my below code does not evaluate true. Please help.

My code below -

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="REGEX(Code__c, '[a-zA-Z]+19-10-11-12[a-zA-Z]+')">

...

</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, however, another way to look at it. You could definitely  work with regex in apex, and then instead of trying to make the regex work in visualforce, just set the output panel as 'rendered'  <apex:outputPanel id="resultsPanel" rendered="{!ShowResults}">

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the expression syntax when calling the functions

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!REGEX(Code__c, '[a-zA-Z]+19-10-11-12[a-zA-Z]+')}">
```

But the REGEX function is not available in Custom Formula Fields or 
Visualforce. check [this reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas)

So you have to either move this logic into the controller or try using javascript to render this.

Comment: As soon as I put it inside {!}, I get an error.

Function REGEX may not be used in this type of formula

Comment: "The REGEX function is not available in Custom Formula Fields or Visualforce." from Vamsi Krishna reference in answer. He's right, you will need to do the formula in APEX, then true/false the rendered in the visualforce page.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm

I can see the function in the visualforce guide.

The only thing that I am confused with is that while most of the functions are enclosed in the VF expression {!} and REGEX is not. But then why include it in the documentation.